# Get id by using url Codes

Tags: javascript, python, url, get, postman

How Can I get the Facebook page id from the URL by using Postman ?
we work on our project to read all Facebook data by codes in postman but we can't get the id from the URL this is our problem.

Comment: Can you give an example? What is the expected input and output

Comment: i want to add a Facebook page URL example(CNN page on Facebook) and postman give me this page id